# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'async'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, Embed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("list")
    .setDescription("Returns an embed.")
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('title')
        .setDescription('description')
        .setColor(fffff)
        .setImage(client.user.displayAvatarUrl())

        await.interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
    channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        })
  }
}
```

```
  async execute(interaction, client) {
  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'async'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\asus\Desktop\bot nexter\handlers\messageHandler.js:10:25)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\asus\Desktop\bot nexter\handlers\index.js:3:35)
```

Comment: There needs to be a comma at the end of `.setDescription()` since `execute` is the *next* key in the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a **comma(,)** at the end of what you type after **data:**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, Embed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("list")
    .setDescription("Returns an embed.")
  ,

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('title')
        .setDescription('description')
        .setColor(fffff)
        .setImage(client.user.displayAvatarUrl())

        await.interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
    channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        })
  }
}
```